# Why do some token accounts own themselves?

Tags: spl-token, account, associated-token-account, owner

I was under the impression that accounts owned by users owned a set of token accounts which each represent one distinct token that they own - meaning token accounts would only be owned by a user. For example, this token account, pointed to by the address `53kn18WWvsx82NiztUXMQGGSuRBujTtLqzszRYK2TgGb`, lists the owner as expected:

```
{
  mint: 'GvLFXp5DqowBtF4nUjXmqx6upH2bjncf2ESndH6ZF1sA',
  owner: '7rhxnLV8C77o6d8oz26AgK8x8m5ePsdeRawjqvojbjnQ',
  amount: '10',
  delegate: null,
  delegatedAmount: '0',
  isInitialized: true,
  isFrozen: false,
  isNative: false,
  rentExemptReserve: null,
  closeAuthority: null
}
```

However, I have found several anomalies where the token account owns itself. For instance, `H6Vb6qdn4pfg1tmqXhVK8WQocsfeUWRhTNZFMjeypsRE`, lists itself as its owner:

```
{
  mint: 'EPjFWdd5AufqSSqeM2qN1xzybapC8G4wEGGkZwyTDt1v',
  owner: 'H6Vb6qdn4pfg1tmqXhVK8WQocsfeUWRhTNZFMjeypsRE',
  amount: '165744535531',
  delegate: null,
  delegatedAmount: '0',
  isInitialized: true,
  isFrozen: false,
  isNative: false,
  rentExemptReserve: null,
  closeAuthority: null
}
```

Solscan also supported my observation:
[image: solscan showing the owner being the same address as the token account]

Other example token accounts that own themselves are `7KFK8aQdrqyxe7V1iuMsP6wRopmqnsDCwAGHwVWE7Tec`, `9o3amSjWDCvKSycLwtZs8vCUkSnim6kjPK5FBXY545eN`, and `J6vHZDKghn3dbTG7pcBLzHMnXFoqUEiHVaFfZxojMjXs`.

Why can some token accounts own themselves?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The owner of a token account is any pubkey. If it's possible to provide signatures for that pubkey, then it's a perfectly valid owner for the token account.

The token program explicitly allows for self-owned accounts, since some people may want to handle multiple keypairs. So you could have separate keypairs owning separate accounts. It can be complicated to manage multiple keypairs and confusing if accounts are self-owned, but it's not incorrect.

You can see where some of this behavior is tested at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/559e2ec8634a7206422ab9660b8695f6b970dab1/token/program/src/processor.rs#L1471

Answer (score 0):

Jon C's answer is correct.

A similar phenomenon also often occurs by accident:

1. Create associated token account (ATA)
2. Close ATA
3. Someone attempts to send tokens to the ATA, specifying it as the recipient
4. Since the ATA was already closed, it is seen as an empty account owned by the System Program, rather than a PDA of the Associated Token Account program. This means a new ATA gets created with the original ATA listed as its owner (oops!). Since ATAs are PDAs, there is no corresponding private key and thus no way to control either account. Except:

This scenario is so common that developers have added the [recover_nested](https://docs.rs/spl-associated-token-account/2.3.0/spl_associated_token_account/instruction/fn.recover_nested.html) instruction to the Association Token Account program to recover from this exact scenario.

In this case, the token account isn't owned by itself, if we're being pedantic. Rather, what *was* a token account suddenly became the owner of another token account.